# How to group data with conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I'm trying to turn my current table using sql

```
customer.id sale_date 
15           1/12/2017
15           2/12/2017
15           7/12/2017
12           6/09/2017
12           12/09/2017
16           8/14/2017
13           6/01/2017
13           7/01/2017
```

into something like this.

`sale_date1` is the first order date.

`sale_date2` is any order date one month after `sale_date1`.

`sale_date3` is any order date five months after `sale_date1`.

```
customer.id sale_date1  sale_date2  sale_date3(at least 5 months after sale_date1)
15           1/12/2017   2/12/2017   7/12/2017 
12           6/07/2017   NULL        12/09/2017
16           8/14/2017   NULL        NULL
13           6/01/2017   7/01/2017   NULL
```

Comment: what is your dbms name?

Comment: How many sales can occur on a single sale date?  Can there be more than 3?

Comment: Welcome to [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). Please share the code which you tried.

Comment: dbms name is orders, only one sale can occur per day

Comment: Not the database name, the server software name. Postgres, MySQL, SQL Server, etc.?

Comment: my server software name is SQL Server

Comment: There could be more than one sale date which is older than 5 months.  Assuming this, _which_ date would you like to report?

Comment: the smaller date

Comment: the same goes for sale_date2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option here would be to use correlated sub-queries to populate each of the three columns:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT [customer.id], MIN(sale_date) AS min_sale_date 
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY [customer.id]
)

SELECT
    [customer.id],
    min_sale_date AS sale_date1,
    (SELECT MIN(t2.sale_date) FROM yourTable t2
     WHERE t1.[customer.id] = t2.[customer.id] AND
           t2.sale_date >= DATEADD(month, 1, t1.min_sale_date) AND
           t2.sale_date <  DATEADD(month, 5, t1.min_sale_date)) AS sale_date2,
    (SELECT MIN(t2.sale_date) FROM yourTable t2
     WHERE t1.[customer.id] = t2.[customer.id] AND
           t2.sale_date >= DATEADD(month, 5, t1.min_sale_date)) AS sale_date3
FROM cte t1
ORDER BY [customer.id];
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: You're right.  Anyway, the confusion comes up because we need to query the original table, but also we need the earliest date for each customer, at the time of that query.

Answer (score 0):

Try below using row_number() and conditional aggregation

```
select customerid,max(case when seq=1 then sale_date end) as date1, 
max(case when seq=2 then sale_date end) as date2,
max(case when seq=3 then sale_date end) as date3
from
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by customerid order by sale_date) as seq
from tablename
)X
group by customerid
```

Comment: How does this address the one and five month requirements?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, from his input table it shows that for customerid sale date is just incremental

Comment: OK, but I think that may just be a coincidence (agreed that the question is not entirely clear).

Answer (score 0):

I THINK THIS IS WHAT YOU WANT

```
SELECT A.customer.id, SALES1.sale_date , SALES2.sale_date ,SALES3.sale_date , SALES4.sale_date,SALES5.sale_date  from 
(SELECT distinct customer.id , 
From yourTable)A 
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * from 
(SELECT customer.id, sale_date 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY sale_date ASC) 
    AS R1,
  name, recovery_model_desc
FROM yourTable)S1 where R1=1)SALES1 
A.customer.id =  SALES1.customer.id
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * from 
(SELECT customer.id, sale_date 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY sale_date ASC) 
    AS R1,
  name, recovery_model_desc
FROM yourTable)S1 where R1=2)SALES2 
A.customer.id =  SALES1.customer.id
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * from 
(SELECT customer.id, sale_date 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY sale_date ASC) 
    AS R1,
  name, recovery_model_desc
FROM yourTable)S1 where R1=3)SALES3 
A.customer.id =  SALES1.customer.id
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * from 
(SELECT customer.id, sale_date 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY sale_date ASC) 
    AS R1,
  name, recovery_model_desc
FROM yourTable)S1 where R1=2)SALES2 
A.customer.id =  SALES1.customer.id
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * from 
(SELECT customer.id, sale_date 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY sale_date ASC) 
    AS R1,
  name, recovery_model_desc
FROM yourTable)S1 where R1=4)SALES4 
A.customer.id =  SALES1.customer.id
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * from 
(SELECT customer.id, sale_date 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY sale_date ASC) 
    AS R1,
  name, recovery_model_desc
FROM yourTable)S1 where R1=2)SALES2 
A.customer.id =  SALES1.customer.id
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * from 
(SELECT customer.id, sale_date 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY sale_date ASC) 
    AS R1,
  name, recovery_model_desc
FROM yourTable)S1 where R1=5)SALES5 
A.customer.id =  SALES1.customer.id
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
with mindate as (
select id, min(sale_date) MinDate, 
DATEADD(month, 1, min(sale_date)) MinDatePlus1Month, 
DATEADD(month, 5, min(sale_date)) MinDatePlus2Month 
from yourtable
group by id
)
select f1.id, f1.MinDate sale_date1, f2.sale_date sale_date2, f3.sale_date sale_date3 
from mindate f1
left outer join yourtable f2 on f1.id=f2.id and f1.MinDatePlus1Month=f2.sale_date
left outer join yourtable f3 on f1.id=f3.id and f1.MinDatePlus2Month=f3.sale_date
```